# How to Get a value from the current SharePoint 2010 pages Page Conent Type?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am looking to create a web part that will get the value of the consuming pages Page Content Type. For instance... I have a Page that has a custom Page Content Type that contains a column called ProductId. I would like to be able to access the value of the field from the web part. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Page Content Type".  Do you mean you have a page with a list and that list is assigned a content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPContext.Current.Item["ProductId"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll take a stab without fully knowing the details.  You can use [SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255.aspx) to create an entity class for your site/subsite and then use [LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491.aspx) to get access to the data in the column.